# HOW TO : Interpolate Client Token Handler from Braintree .NET sdk to Client

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, braintree

I am fairly new to web development and have mostly worked with VB and WinForms. I have taken on building a small e-commerce site for a client and have decided to use Braintree to handle transactions. However, I am having trouble getting a server generated client token to the client Braintree UI drop-in form. I have created a default handler as they recommend.

```
public class ClientTokenHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public string pubClientToken;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
        {
            Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
            MerchantId = "MerchantID",
            PublicKey = "Public_Key",
            PrivateKey = "Private_Key"
        };
       pubClientToken = gateway.ClientToken.generate();
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pubClientToken);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint at the beginning of the handler so that when I call the handler from the client to get the client token, I can make sure that the token is generated. Yet, the breakpoint is never hit and the drop-in UI never loads (I assume because it doesn't have a valid token). Here is my code for the AJAX call to the handler.

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
    <div id="payment-form"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
    </form>

    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.22.2.min.js"></script>

   <script>
       var clientToken;
       function CallHandler() {
           $.ajax({
               url: "ClientTokenHandler.ashx.cs",
               type: "GET",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: OnComplete,
               error: OnFail
           });
           return result;

           function OnComplete(result) {
               clientToken = data;
           }
           function OnFail(result) {
               alert('Request failed');

           }
       }

    // We generated a client token for you so you can test out this code
    // immediately. In a production-ready integration, you will need to
       // generate a client token on your server (see section below).
       //var clientToken = "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";


    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
    container: "payment-form"
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Does anybody have an example of how they would/did do it? This is my first post, please don't throw too many stones. ;) TIA!

Comment: I included a <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> and it now stops at my breakpoint. However, now when I interpolate the client token into the dropin UI, I get an error in my browser that says, "Uncaught Error: Braintree API Client Misconfigured: clientToken required." It even happens if I pause the debugger and manually inject the token generated by their server!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it on my own. I apparently wasn't referencing the correct JQuery script. Oh, and I had to change the 'type:' to POST. Here is my final working code to get the Braintree generated client token and pass to the client.

```
<div class="container">
        <form id="checkout" method="post" action="/Checkout">
        <div id="payment-form"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
        </form>

        <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.22.2.min.js"></script>

       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //AJAX call to get clientToken from ClientTokenHandler
           var clientToken;
            $(document).ready(function CallHandler() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ClientTokenHandler.ashx",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    datatype: "text",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        clientToken = data;
                        braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
                            container: "payment-form"
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            //End call
         </script>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps somebody else along the way!